# Как мне вывести массив значения свойства автора в которого рейтинг больше 8?

Tags: javascript, filter

```
livre = [
 { title: "Redder Than Blood", author: "Tanith Lee", rating: 7.94 },
  {
    title: "The Dreams in the Witch House",
    author: "Howard Lovecraft",
    rating: 8.67,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forEach**

Выводит массивы авторов

```
livre.forEach(element => { if(element['rating'] > 8) console.log(element) });
```

**filter**

Возвращает массив массивов авторов

```
livre.filter(el => { if(el['rating'] > 8) return true } )
```

Comment: `{ if(el['rating'] > 8) return true }`  ---> `el['rating'] > 8`